# Is too much sun better than full shade for Haworthias?

Tags: pests, succulents, light

I recently had several scale-aphids attacks. It involves many of the shaded Haworthias. Systemic insecticides, soap-water blasting, removing and cleaning rotted roots and affected areas, weak bleach solution, fixing soil/drainage issues had no effect. All attacks were in the summer, the dormant season. Waiting to fall awakening, however, is too much time for a sick plant.

I noticed that rooted cuttings which were in full sun appeared red and wrinkled, but a close inspection showed healthy plants, fully-developed roots and a green healthy rosette at the center. Moving affected plants, even gradually, seems futile. They must have been there from the start.

So based on that, should I adjust all my so-far healthy Haworthias to full-sun exposure?